# Suggestions for Android project guidelines

Tags: android, coding-style

I'm trying to prepare a set of guidelines and project template for my future Android projects. Im already implementing the basic MVC architecture modularity. Im trying to have add more advanced level of design to my Android projects to make my development easier and maintainable.

For example can someone suggest me a way to make Intent calls to Activity without explicitly mentioning the class while creating the Intent. Im trying to loose couple the intent calls and hopefully use AndroidManifest to assign action to an activity which then can be called globally within the application.

Any other type of suggestions are welcome.

Also please suggest any kind of coding conventions that you might be using yourself.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call an Activity without explicity set the Activity class in the Intent you could register a broadcast receiver in your activity for your custom action..

Have a look at [registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) function.